# how can i show different image per clicks

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to build one app called workout helper and I am on learning phase and I am confused how can i show different image per clicks. like as you can see the code when i run app it shows me lists of images , and when i click on back image its opening new activity call Main_actvity2 with same images , so what i want to do is i want to show diffrent images , if i click on back , its need to be show only back workout and if chest than only chest workout.
i understand that i need to create also one new activity to show workouts but i am not understanding how to show only back images on back clicks ,and  chest images on chest clicks etc

**here is activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**here is Mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<Exercise_details> exercise_details;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    exercise_details = new ArrayList<>();
    exercise_details.add(new Exercise_details("Back",R.drawable.back));
    exercise_details.add(new Exercise_details("Bicheps",R.drawable.bicheps));
    exercise_details.add(new Exercise_details("Chest",R.drawable.chest));
    exercise_details.add(new Exercise_details("Tricheps",R.drawable.tricheps));
    exercise_details.add(new Exercise_details("Shoulder",R.drawable.shoulder));
    exercise_details.add(new Exercise_details("Legs",R.drawable.legs));



    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,1));
    Main_Exersize_Adapter main_exersize_adapter = new Main_Exersize_Adapter(this,exercise_details);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(main_exersize_adapter);
}
```

}

**here is activity main2.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main_Activity2">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**and here is activitymain2.java**

```
public class Main_Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<Exersize_details2> ED;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


    recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
    ED = new ArrayList<>();

    ED.add(new Exersize_details2("Back" , R.drawable.back));
    ED.add(new Exersize_details2("Bicheps" , R.drawable.bicheps));
    ED.add(new Exersize_details2("Chest" , R.drawable.chest));
    ED.add(new Exersize_details2("Tricheps" , R.drawable.tricheps));
    ED.add(new Exersize_details2("Shoulder" , R.drawable.shoulder));
    ED.add(new Exersize_details2("Legs" , R.drawable.legs));

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,1));
    Main_Exersize_Adapter2 m2 =  new Main_Exersize_Adapter2(this,ED);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(m2);

}
```

}

**and here is MainExersize_Adapter**

```
public class Main_Exersize_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Main_Exersize_Adapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Exercise_details> exercise_details;


public Main_Exersize_Adapter(Context context, List<Exercise_details> exercise_details) {
    this.context = context;
    this.exercise_details = exercise_details;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.main_exercise,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.workout_image.setImageResource(exercise_details.get(position).getThumb());
    holder.exersize_title.setText(exercise_details.get(position).getExtitle());
    holder.cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main_Activity2.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return exercise_details.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView workout_image;
    private TextView exersize_title;
    private CardView cardview;
    private ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        workout_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.workout_image);
        exersize_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exersize_title);
        cardview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
    }
}
```

}

**and here is MainExersize_Adapter2**

```
public class Main_Exersize_Adapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Main_Exersize_Adapter2.ViewHolder2> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Exersize_details2> m2;

public Main_Exersize_Adapter2(Context mContext, List<Exersize_details2> m2) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.m2 = m2;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder2 onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.main_exersize2,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder2(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder2 holder, int position) {
    holder.workout_image2.setImageResource(m2.get(position).getThumb2());
    holder.exersize_title2.setText(m2.get(position).getExtitle2());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return m2.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView workout_image2;
    private TextView exersize_title2;
    private ViewHolder2(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        workout_image2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.workout_image2);
        exersize_title2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exersize_title2);
    }
}
```

}

**and here is Exersize_details.java**

```
public class Exercise_details {
private String Extitle;
private int  Thumb;

public Exercise_details() {
}

public Exercise_details(String extitle, int thumb) {
    Extitle = extitle;
    Thumb = thumb;
}

public String getExtitle() {
    return Extitle;
}

public void setExtitle(String extitle) {
    Extitle = extitle;
}

public int getThumb() {
    return Thumb;
}

public void setThumb(int thumb) {
    Thumb = thumb;
}
```

}

**and here is Exersize_details2.java**

```
public class Exersize_details2 {
private String Extitle2;
private int  Thumb2;

public Exersize_details2() {
}

public Exersize_details2(String extitle2, int thumb2) {
    Extitle2 = extitle2;
    Thumb2 = thumb2;
}

public String getExtitle2() {
    return Extitle2;
}

public void setExtitle2(String extitle2) {
    Extitle2 = extitle2;
}

public int getThumb2() {
    return Thumb2;
}

public void setThumb2(int thumb2) {
    Thumb2 = thumb2;
}
```

}

Comment: Check your images, both are same, edit your question again

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow. As it stands this question is likely to be flagged or downvoted as it is not asking anything specific to programming. Please show minimal examples of reproducible code and show the exact error you are encountering.

Comment: thanks for reply bro, you didn't understand bro , i have added both same images bcs in 2nd one i want to show everywhere only back workout images and like this for others workouts as well , you understand now?

Comment: its still confusing n same images

Comment: @Ars Developer I'm not sure if I understood you right, but I guess you want to make all irrelevant images invisible and show only one image on the second activity. Try to hide the all the images that you don't want to show with `ImageView.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE);` Does this help you further?

Comment: can you pls add me on skype and help me to solve this it will be appreciated bro as i am learning , i don't want to giive up 
here is my skype live:hrtlgghg579

Comment: no bro i mean is that , like see if you can see there is 2 images in 1 images i am showing all workout images and than when i click  on  chest or any other image than it send me to 2nd image as you can see in 2nd image i am getting same images , instead on same images i want to show only chest workout images in lists like this in other also , if you still didn't understand can you pls add me on skype and help me to resolve this 
my skype live:hrtlgghg579@gmail.com

Comment: @Ars Developer I understood you, that's why I suggested you to change the visibility for the images that you don't want to show. If you want to keep their order use `INVISIBLE`, if not use `GONE`.
ex. `chestImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
shoulderImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` and so on...

Sorry, I can't use Skype because of our corporate policies.

Comment: i understand but how can i show other images ?

Comment: i got it, what you mean to say, are you using list view to diplay those images? if yes, post the code of onclicklistner of listview n setting of values in adapters

Comment: well i will send you whole project file and you will understand , somehow by mistake i converted java to kotlin and deleted that project , i am creating it again [ sad life] , i am sending soon and thx for the help bro <3

Comment: ok bro i have added code, now i hope you understand whats the issue

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on the ID, remove the above ID from the database and save it to A, then extract the desired photos from the database after saving the ID. Earned by using ID

Comment: i didn't understand your ans can you pls add me on skype ?pls

Comment: Share project file

Comment: https://mega.nz/#F!vvpGHKqC!ZapYWOXluhNZ7GWj5LFIsg
sorry i don't know how to upload it on github

Answer (score 0):

After click on selected category,get selected id of category and fetch data according.

Comment: for that i need to make new Activity right ?and pls check code